# EPPlus throwing Argument Exception (Negative row and column numbers are not allowed)

Tags: vb.net, epplus

I'm using EPPlus 2.9.0.1 with Visual Basic.

I have a DataTable with 35 Rows and 4 Columns and the code below:

```
Dim FullFilePath As String = "c:\Report.xlxs"

Dim newFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(FullFilePath)

Using package As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(newFile)
    Dim worksheet As ExcelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Relatório")
    worksheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(gSystemTable, False)
    package.Save()
End Using
```

When method 'LoadFromDataTable' is called, I get an ArgumentException (Negative row and Columns numbers are not allowed). I don't have negative numbers in row or column numbers, as far I know.

Why this error is happening?

Comment: Getting the same error with C#... How did you handle this exception???

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the range where you want to add the data to the worksheet.

For example:

```
worksheet.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(gSystemTable, False)
```