# Create Excel file based on Multiple Excel files C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, merge, xlsx

I have three Excel Workbooks such as WorkBookA, WorkBookB and WorkBookC.
Each workbook which has one sheet such as SheetA, SheetB and SheetC.

I want to create a new excel file with SheetA from WorkBookA, SheetB from WorkBookB and SheetC from WorkBookC.

How to do this? Any suggestions..?

Answer (score 0):

This should be very easy.

1. Grab some code which reads in a particular worksheet into a `DataTable`. There are plenty of examples showing how to do this, eg.
   [Excel to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577184/importing-excel-into-a-datatable-quickly)
2. Create a `DataSet` containing the three `DataTables`.
3. Finally, call my "Export to Excel" library to write this DataSet into a real .xlsx file, [Export to Excel](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm)