# C# Using data from Excel to simulate a Signal over time

Tags: c#, excel, import, timestamp, signals

is there any good way how i can import a Excel file with signal values (40,000 values, ~100 minutes measurement time) and simulate a signal over time with it?

I want to reconstruct the simulation with timestamp and Signal values.

I've two columns:

- Timestamp for every value (it isn't equidistant)
- Signal-Value

The timestamp should be nearly synchron with the simulationtime.

Maybe someone has a good "to start" idea?

Thank you!

**Update #1 (based on the comments):**

@Wouter de Kort: I got data from measurement over time. I got for every timestamp a value. The data looks something like this (without backslash):

> Time (s) //   Value
>
> 154,51    //    49,33
>
> 154,71    //  49,46
>
> 154,92    //    49,72
>
> 155,11    //    49,64

I only want to look from the beginning to the end of the data over a time (the time, the measurement in real took). Like a Sinus Generator, but in this case i've a specific signal and the values has to be at a specific time.

How can i export it to CSV? And what are the benefits using CSV with C# instead of Excel?

Update #2:

My case is, to get every (e.g.) 100ms a new value through a variable which i can use for my visualization program i already have.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you want to do? Can you show some sample data? What is the result you expect from your code? What does reconstructing a simulation mean? Machine learning or just looping through some data and running some code?

Comment: Export it to a CSV or something similarly easy to read, should be easy going from there.

Comment: I would suggest to concentrate on the very first part of your task: to find a way to import just ANY data (like contents of a single cell as a string) from Excel file into your application.

Comment: I will answer @update #1

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [Importing Excel into a DataTable Quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577184/importing-excel-into-a-datatable-quickly) There's an importing example directly from an Excel spreadsheet without the need to convert to CSV.

You can also use OfficeOpenXml. It provides a way to access cell data like so:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
...
var pck = new ExcelPackage(fileName);
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.ElementAt(0);  // first worksheet
ws.Select();
var value = ws.Cells[row, col].Value;           // corresponds to some Excel cell value
```

Comment: I want to generate a signal based on the values. So my case is, to get every (e.g.) 100ms a new value through a variable which i can use for my visualization program i already have.