# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'object[*,*]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I need to give the value of Range into a multidimensional object but error occurs:

Cannot implicitly convert type `object` to `object[*,*]`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here is the code:

```
Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(rtbExcelPath.Text.Trim(), Missing.Value, 
Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 
Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 
Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

Excel.Worksheet oWS = oWB.Worksheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;

int countRows = oWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
int countColumns = oWS.UsedRange.Columns.Count;

object[,] data = oWS.Range[oWS.Cells[1, 1], oWS.Cells[countRows, 
countColumns]].Cells.Value2;
```

Please help to check what is wrong... :(

Comment: Which line throws the error? Is it when you are trying to open the workbook?

Comment: this one:
object[,] data = oWS.Range[oWS.Cells[1, 1], oWS.Cells[countRows, 
countColumns]].Cells.Value2;

Comment: Value2 returns the value of a specific cell, it won't be an array.  Google "c# excel copy range into array" to find code, too many hits to recommend the best one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will occur when `oWS.UsedRange` references a single cell.  In this case, the object returned is a single value and not an array.  If you want an array, you will need to test for this case and explicitly create it.

```
object[,] data;
if (oWS.UsedRange.Cells.CountLarge == 1)
{
    // create a single cell two dimensional array with 1 based 
    // lower bounds to simular to an array returned by Excel
    data = (object[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new[]{1, 1}, new[]{1, 1});
    data[1, 1] = oWS.UsedRange.Value2;
}
else
{
    data = oWS.UsedRange.Value2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve your issue by using the `dynamic` variable type instead of explicit type `object[,]`.

```cs
dynamic data = oWS.Range[oWS.Cells[1, 1], oWS.Cells[countRows, 
countColumns]].Cells.Value2;
```

Comment: how can i cast it to multidimensional object?  because i need to have a multidimensional object array for my codes..

Comment: Without digging into the Interop.Excel namespace could you extract each cell value to your multi-dimensional array with nested looping?

Comment: I need to have a nested loop that's why I need to have multidimensional object array..  
Because what I really want is to use the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577184/importing-excel-into-a-datatable-quickly

but I cannot do it because I am not able to succesfully have the    object[,] data

Comment: I added an example of extracting the cell values to a multi-dimensional array.  Hopefully that gets you moving towards a valid solution.

Comment: I need to have a nested loop that's why I need to have multidimensional object array.. Because what I really want is to use the answer from stackoverflow.com/questions/17577184/… but I cannot do it because I am not able to succesfully have the object[,] data

Comment: that same nested loops you added is the one I'm trying to solve that's why I need the multidimensional object array

Comment: @user3200634, I did some additional digging based upon your comments.  The interface seems odd to me, but I was able to get it working with ```dynamic```.  You'll need to add a reference to the Microsoft.CSharp built-in library if your application does not already have it.