# Convert Excel cell range into DataTable C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I want to read a selected cell range of Excel sheet into a DataTable without using OLEDB. And I don't want to use 3rd party tools either.

Here is what I have done so far:

```cs
public void converter() 
{
    xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = xlWorkbook.Worksheets;
    xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[3];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        range = xlWorksheet.get_Range("A2", "I8");
        System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value;
        //string[] strArray = ConvertToStringArray(myvalues);
        //List<string> lst = myvalues.OfType<string>().ToList();
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

After Googling, I ended up with following but I do not know how to make it work with cell range

```cs
public System.Data.DataTable READExcel(string path)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objXL = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objWB = null;
    objXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Open(path);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objSHT = objWB.Worksheets[5];
    
    int rows = objSHT.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
    int cols = objSHT.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    int noofrow = 1;
    
    for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
    {
        string colname = objSHT.Cells[1, c].Text;
        dt.Columns.Add(colname);
        noofrow = 2;
    }
    
    for (int r = noofrow; r <= rows; r++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
        {
            dr[c - 1] = objSHT.Cells[r, c].Text;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    
    objWB.Close();
    objXL.Quit();
    return dt;
}
```

Kindly help me achieve this.

Comment: Hi can you please help me with the errors or output you got and output you need to get?

Comment: Hi @saikiran, thank you for your interest. I am not getting any error. But with the first method, I have not been able to read the range into DataTable. With the second method, I do not know how to specify cell range. For example, all cells between A2 and I8 or A9 and I19.

Comment: Will someone please help me?

Comment: ```range.Value2``` gives you an Array of the values in that range or one string(if the range has only one cell). For the 2nd Example, you would have to manipulate the for loops start and end parameters to match your range: ```for (int r = _startrowindex_; r <= _endrowindex_; r++)``` and ```for (int c = _startcolumnindex_; c <= _endcolumnindex_; c++)``` (experiment with the ```<=```, might be ```<``` too). Although in you code ```noofrow``` looks like chaos, it will be set to 1, then in the for loop x times to 2 and stays at this value... confusing and might be a bug

Comment: @FrankM, thank you for your interest and help. May I see some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect and you might need to tweek some parameters, I didn't check if it gets the correct area, thats your work.
But it gets a DataTable out of an Excel Worksheet, as you asked.

I'd prefer creating an custom object list with the columns as properties, rather than a DataTable, but thats only me.

```
public System.Data.DataTable READExcel(string path,int row,int col, int rowamount, int colamount, int worksheetindex)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objXL = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objWB = null;
    objXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Open(path);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objSHT = objWB.Worksheets[worksheetindex];

    int rows = objSHT.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
    int cols = objSHT.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            
    // Change that for other column names
    for (int c = col; c <= col + colamount; c++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(objSHT.Cells[row, c].Text);
    }        
    // read the content
    for (int r = row; r <= row+rowamount; r++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int c = col; c <= col+colamount; c++)
        {
            dr[c - 1] = objSHT.Cells[r, c].Text;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    objWB.Close();
    objXL.Quit();
    return dt;
}
```

Call it like that:

```
// A2 -> row:2,col:1 till F6 row:2+4, col1+5
READExcel(@"path", 2, 1, 4, 5, 3);
```

The faster way would be using Value2, example: `var range = xlWorksheet.Range["A3", "B4"].Value2;` (get_Range() doesn't work with my excel)
and iterate over it, filling the DataTable. `range[1,1]` would be the content of A3 in this example.

Comment: Thank you, I have tested it a little bit. It works, almost.
`READExcel(@"path", 2, 1, 4, 5, new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" },3);`
I don't want number of columns to be hard coded. It should be determined by the range defined(2,1,4,5).

Comment: Now I changed it to do so, but if you arent even able to do such little changes, maybe you should pay someone to do the work for you.

Comment: @theLuckyOne: I spent time and effort into answering your question and it seemed to help you out - saving you time and effort. Please mark my answer as such and consider upvoting as a little reward.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for the delay in accepting answer. Really. I have upvoted it too. And again, thank you so much.