# Cannot find column '0' C#

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have the following piece of code.

```
dt3 = new System.Data.DataTable();
            foreach (DataRow sourceRow in dt2.Rows) {
                DataRow destRow = dt3.NewRow();
                destRow[0] = sourceRow[2];
                dt3.Rows.Add(destRow);
            }
```

And it is generating following error on line `destRow[0] = sourceRow[2];`

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column 0.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way around it without declaring columns beforehand?

Comment: You seem to already know the answer: Add a column.

Comment: And you probably want: `destRow[0].Value = sourceRow[2].Value;`

Comment: Thank you for responding, can't columns be generated on the fly?

Comment: .Value ain't valid for this object.

Comment: Why do you need to generate columns on the fly? You can, but the code you have there doesn't indicate a need to.

Comment: Wrong code won't show the intent. I want to create a new DataTable(dt3) from a select few columns of previously declared DataTable(dt2).

Comment: @HenkHolterman, since you are here, could you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66778315/convert-excel-cell-range-into-datatable-c-sharp please?

Comment: @JonSkeet No. I'll know which columns I want at runtime. Because the source DataTable will be filled at runtime.

Comment: @theLuckyOne Then where's the problem? Grab those columns, copy them to a new table, copy the rows.

Comment: @Llama. Problem is, I don't know how. Your example makes sense but it has a precondition of having the programmer know which columns will the user be copying.

Comment: @theLuckyOne In case there's any misunderstanding, `srcDataTable` in my example is meant to be your `dt2`, and `desiredColumns` in the first example is the names of the columns you want to copy, and in the second example it's the indices of the columns you want to copy. You don't need to hardcode these values. They're hardcoded in my example solely so that it's a runnable example if you copy it into Visual Studio. You can pass the values in from somewhere else. They do not need to be known at compile time. They only have to correspond to the columns in `dt2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we create a "source" DataTable with 3 columns, and select two of those columns for the new DataTable:

```
DataTable srcDataTable = new DataTable();
srcDataTable.Columns.Add("Column A", typeof(string));
srcDataTable.Columns.Add("Column B", typeof(int));
srcDataTable.Columns.Add("Column C", typeof(int));

DataTable dstDataTable = new DataTable();
var desiredColumns = new[] { "Column A", "Column C" };
foreach (DataColumn col in srcDataTable.Columns)
{
    if (desiredColumns.Contains(col.ColumnName))
    {
        dstDataTable.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType, col.Expression);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply loop through the source table and copy the row data as you need it. Example for copying the rows:

```
foreach (DataRow srcRow in srcDataTable.Rows)
{
    var newRow = dstDataTable.NewRow();
    foreach (var columnName in desiredColumns)
    {
        newRow[columnName] = srcRow[columnName];
    }
    dstDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

---

Alternative approach using column numbers:

```
DataTable srcDataTable = new DataTable();
srcDataTable.Columns.Add("Column A", typeof(string));
srcDataTable.Columns.Add("Column B", typeof(int));
srcDataTable.Columns.Add("Column C", typeof(int));

DataTable dstDataTable = new DataTable();
var desiredColumns = new int[] { 0, 2 };
Dictionary<int, int> columnMap = new Dictionary<int, int>();

for (int colNum = 0; colNum < desiredColumns.Length; ++colNum)
{
    columnMap[colNum] = desiredColumns[colNum];
    dstDataTable.Columns.Add(srcDataTable.Columns[desiredColumns[colNum]].ColumnName, srcDataTable.Columns[desiredColumns[colNum]].DataType, srcDataTable.Columns[desiredColumns[colNum]].Expression);
}

foreach (DataRow srcRow in srcDataTable.Rows)
{
    var newRow = dstDataTable.NewRow();
    for (int colNum = 0; colNum < desiredColumns.Length; ++colNum)
    {
        newRow[colNum] = srcRow[columnMap[colNum]];
    }
    dstDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Comment: Okay, let me try. Thank you.

Comment: How do I know at the time of coding that my source table is going to have columns as such

`srcDataTable.Columns.Add("Column A", typeof(string));
srcDataTable.Columns.Add("Column B", typeof(int));
srcDataTable.Columns.Add("Column C", typeof(int));`

Comment: @theLuckyOne There isn't a magic wand solution here. You want to copy a subset of columns from your source datatable to your new one. You must have _some way_ of determining which columns you want to copy, surely? Otherwise what is the point of all of this?

Comment: Source table is being populated with different SQL tables at different times.

Comment: my point is that I can't know the column name and type before program is executed.

Comment: @theLuckyOne Then what you're trying to do is 100% impossible.

Comment: @theLuckyOne: So access the columns by number instead of by name. I'm not quite sure why you're *so* focused on "I don't know anything until execution time" - your code already shows you know the number of the column whose value you want to copy, so you can use that to fetch the existing `DataColumn`, then create the new column for the new table.

Comment: @Llama: I disagree - they don't know the name, but according to the code in the question, they know the column *number*, and that's all that's required.

Comment: @JonSkeet I asked OP how they determine what columns they want to copy, and OP simply stated that data is being populated from different SQL tables at different times. They seem reluctant to provide this information, which suggests to me that they don't have it. Without any programatic means of determining which columns they want to copy, it would seem impossible to get the correct result. If they have column number then fine, then that's a way of determining the column to copy, but all suggestions so far seem to be that they don't even have this.

Comment: @JonSkeet. The column number is there as a proof of concept thing. Later it will be a variable.

Comment: @theLuckyOne What you've told us: 1) You have a DataTable with unknown columns. 2) You want to copy a subset of those columns, and the corresponding row data, to a new DataTable. 3) You have no means of identifying which columns (by name, number, anything else) you want to copy. On that basis, this seems impossible. On the other hand, if you do have a means of identifying the columns (by name or number) that you want to copy, then you have your answer already.

Comment: @Llama Alright, I thought it could be done. But thank you so much for sparing your time and patience. Really.

Comment: @theLuckyOne I've added an alternative approach using column numbers. Hopefully when you have the information in your possession as to how to determine which columns to copy, this answer might be useful to you.

Comment: @theLuckyOne: "Later it will be a variable." So use that variable to access the column. We've shown you, across answers and comments: a) how to get a DataColumn from an existing table, either by number or by name; b) how to create a new DataColumn based on an existing one; c) how to add a DataColumn to the new table. It really feels like we've bent over backwards to help you, and the response seems to permanently be "I can't do it because I only know things at runtime" even though the solutions we've provided allow you to specify that column at runtime.

Comment: @Llama. Thank you so much. I have tested the code and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This line `dt3 = new System.Data.DataTable();` creates a new DataTable. But this table doesn't contain any columns yet. In fact, it's an empty table.

This line `destRow[0] = sourceRow[2];` tries to set the value of the first column of your table. However, your table doesn't contain any columns yet. And this is what the error message is trying to tell you.

You have to create your column after creating the table. You can do it like this:

```
DataColumn idColumn = new DataColumn();
idColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
idColumn.ColumnName = "id";
dt3.Columns.Add(idColumn);
```

Only after this, you will be able to put data into your first column.

Please take a look at [this example in the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=net-5.0)

Comment: No, I want to create columns on the fly. Just like in the case when we are reading data from SQL into a datatable.

Comment: @theLuckyOne: Why not copy columns that you want to use from the source table?

Comment: @JonSkeet, that is what I am trying to achieve. Copy selected columns into another datatable.

Comment: @JonSkeet, could you also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66778315/convert-excel-cell-range-into-datatable-c-sharp please?

Comment: The DataTable needs to know what type of columns you are creating and what constraints apply to them. That's why I don't think you can create the columns on the fly. But as @BorisSh pointed out, you can use the Clone() method to copy the source table schema. This way you will have a table with initialized columns.

Comment: @theLuckyOne: Right, so you should call `dt3.Columns.Add`, having created a new `DataColumn` from the one in the existing `DataTable`. Don't just expect to be able to copy a value into a non-existent column. (And please don't use comments to try to get attention for other questions.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, exisiting `DataTable` comes into existence at runtime.

Comment: @theLuckyOne: I don't see the relevance of that. What's to stop you from having code *exactly* like the code in this answer, but populating the `DataType` and `ColumnName` from the existing column, e.g. `var newColumn = new DataColumn(oldColumn.ColumnName, oldColumn.DataType);`? (Where `oldColumn` is from the source table, and where you then add `newColumn` to the new table.)

Comment: @JonSkeet. I can't because the source table is being filled at runtime.

Comment: @theLuckyOne "The source table is being filled at runtime." - Yes, using precisely the same methods that you can use to add tables to the new table! .NET is using those methods internally. You can literally loop through the columns in the existing table, check if the name of each column is one you want to keep, and then create a new column in the way Jon and uodami described.

Comment: @theLuckyOne: What part of the code I provided you shows *anything* that needs to be known at compile-time?

Comment: @JonSkeet, at compile time, I don't know if my source table if going to have a column named 'ID' with data type Int32.

Comment: @theLuckyOne: Where did the code in my comment at 2021-03-25T07:06:15Z (not this answer, which was not from me) say anything about `ID` or `Int32`? You clearly know which columns you need in *some* form, because you're copying the data from them.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

Table `dt3` has no column 0, because you haven't added one

> Is there any way around it without declaring columns beforehand?

Even though you don't necessarily know the column name or type of dt2's column 2 at compile time, you seem to know that you definitely want column 2 from `dt2` to be column 0 of `dt3`, so make sure you add a column to dt3 that is the same type (and giving it the same name seems reasonable too) as column 2 of dt2:

```
        dt3 = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt3.Columns.Add(dt2.Columns[2].ColumnName, dt2.Columns[2].DataType); 
        foreach (DataRow sourceRow in dt2.Rows) {
            DataRow destRow = dt3.NewRow();
            destRow[0] = sourceRow[2];
            dt3.Rows.Add(destRow);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Clone() method to copy structure/columns from source table to destination table:

```
var dt3 = dt2.Clone();
```

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.clone?view=net-5.0).