# How can I read Excel file?

Tags: c#

I want to read excell file with this code:

```
var fileName = @"d:\1.xlsx"; 
var connectionString = string.Format(
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source="+fileName+
    "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet();

adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere");

DataTable data = ds.Tables["anyNameHere"];
```

But when run the program I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: External table is not in the expected format.

How can i solve that?

Comment: This answer is very highly rated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1363480/49 try it maybe

Comment: you should take a look at this site https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Answer (score 3):

Your excel file is 2007 version, *.xlsx and you are using the wrong provider(Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0).

Try this approach:

```
var fileName = @"d:\1.xlsx"; 
var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Its already answer the question in the past post Please follow the below link

[Answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261655/best-fastest-way-to-read-an-excel-sheet-into-a-datatable)

The answer is very simple

```
sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Test.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have diff version of Excel file, get the file name, if its extension is .xlsx, use this

```
var fileName = @"d:\1.xlsx"; 
var connectionString = string.Format(
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="{0}";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this Libary called [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/example_exceldatalink.html). Since discovering it i have never written the plumbing code myself. It lets you concentrate on the actual business logic.