# Finding rows that contain the same values as each other between two columns

Tags: vb.net, excel

Each row in my workbook is a building ID. Each column in my workbook is an item ID.

The cell at the intersection of each item and each building contains a number. This number indicates the quantity of that item in that building. If the building does not have the item, a zero is placed in the intersecting cell.

I need to know which buildings are identical in inventory, that is, which buildings have the same items and the same quantities of said items.

To do this I wrote a script that copies the entire range of intersections for each building to the clipboard, and then pastes it into a cell I refer to as a DNA cell. This DNA cell is just a long, concatenated string of all the intersection numbers.

At the end of the process I would examine which ones had duplicate DNA strings and go from there.

I got it to work, however it is extremely slow, even with screen updating off. Granted I am doing a worksheet with 214 columns and 150 rows, but I still feel like it should go faster.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I want? Basically I need to, for each row, find out if the values in all the cells between D and the last column in that row are identical to any other row.

So if row 75 and row 96 both had the same values in every column between D and the last column, they would be considered "alike" and I would flag them.

My code is below:

```
        ' start excel application 
    oXL = New Excel.Application
    oXL.Visible = True
    ' Get a new workbook.

    oXL.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add


    oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet

    oWB.Worksheets(1).range("a1").select()
    oWB.Worksheets(1).Paste()

    oSheet.UsedRange.Copy()
    oWB.Worksheets.Add()
    Dim transposeSheet As Worksheet

    oWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").range("a1").select()
    oWB.Worksheets("Sheet2").range("a1").PasteSpecial(Transpose:=True)

    transposeSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet

    With transposeSheet




        .Columns("c:c").Insert(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Constants.xlRight)
    End With

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As String
    Dim xlCells As Excel.Range = transposeSheet.Cells
    Dim xlTempRange As Excel.Range = xlCells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell)
    lastRow = xlTempRange.Row
    lastCol = xlTempRange.Column
    Dim columnLetter As String = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(lastCol)
    lastCol = columnLetter

    Dim DNAholder As String
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In transposeSheet.Range("c6:c" & lastRow)

        isLooping = True

        If stopPlz = True Then

            stopPlz = False
            isLooping = False
            oXL.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Exit For
        End If

        transposeSheet.Range("d" & c.Row & ":" & lastCol & c.Row).Copy()
        DNAholder = Clipboard.GetText
        c.Value = DNAholder

    Next c

    isLooping = False
    oXL.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you NEED to do with the results of this. Do you need it in the spreadsheet or something else? The best way is to work with this like a database table, not through interop (nor using the clipboard). Try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261655/best-fastest-way-to-read-an-excel-sheet-into-a-datatable

Comment: Basically I am going to end up displaying to the user two things: Groups of buildings that have the exact same products and same quantity of each product, and buildings that just have the same products.

Comment: Don't copy paste. Use arrays.