# variable value to store procedure parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Hello I'm having an issue passing the value  to SP parameter, inline query is working fine.
My task is to select  multiple items from the dorpdownlist and display it in a gridview. 
I have two dropdown when I select the value from first dropdown then second dropdown is filled on the basis of the first dropdown from db on button click.

Here is what I have done so far,

```
     protected void btnGetResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedListValue = hdnSelections.Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedListValue))
        {
            string[] finalList = selectedListValue.TrimEnd(',').Split(',');

            var parameters = new string[finalList.Length];
            var cmd = new SqlCommand();
            for (int i = 0; i < finalList.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(finalList[i]))
                {
                    parameters[i] = string.Format("@cardcode{0}", i);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameters[i],finalList[i]);
                }
            }

           cmd.CommandText = string.Format("Select cardcode, FirstName from 
          nonSAPcustomer where cardcode IN ({0})", string.Join(", ", 
            parameters));
          // cmd.CommandText= string.Format("sp_nonSAPcustomer", 
            parameters);
            cmd.Connection = Connection.con;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            lstBoxcities.DataSource = dt;
            lstBoxcities.DataValueField = "cardcode";
            lstBoxcities.DataTextField = "FirstName";
            lstBoxcities.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: What is the code doing now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Add a question to your question.

Comment: @mjwills , my code is  slecting the name  name from the first dropdown list and on the selection of first dropdown , second dropdown is filling

Comment: @mjwills , this code is using the inline query to fill the dropdown from the database, i want to use the SP instead of inline query

Comment: I suggest you look at the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261655/best-fastest-way-to-read-an-excel-sheet-into-a-datatable

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Table-Valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine).

First, create a Type:

```
CREATE TYPE CardCodes AS TABLE ( CardCode INT);
```

Then, add a parameter of that type

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProc
    @Codes CardCodes READONLY 
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT *
     FROM FOO
     WHERE ID IN(SELECT Code From @Codes)
END
```

And then send the values using, though I think there are other recipes, I use DataTables:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("CardCode", typeof(int));

PopulateTable(dataTable);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Codes", dataTable);
```