# Facing error while loading data from Excel Sheet to DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new 
OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + ";IMEX=1;Readonly=1;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;\""))
{
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
        {
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
    }
}
```

The above is the code I am using and getting the below **error**:

> Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.

Have someone faced the same issue?

Comment: Add READONLY=FALSE; to connection string.

Comment: @RahulSharma Still facing the issue :(

Comment: Refer to this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/822c9afb-3302-4810-86aa-1eb1ac46d000/odbc-and-excel-database-or-object-is-readonly?forum=adodotnetdataproviders and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261655/best-fastest-way-to-read-an-excel-sheet-into-a-datatable

Comment: @RahulSharma Didnt help :(

Comment: What excel version are you using and which on what bit environment are you running your Visual Studio? Is it 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your connection string contains "Readonly=1;". try changing "Readonly=0;". And try to remove "imex=1". So your code should be someting like that:

```
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new 
OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + ";Readonly=0;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;\""))
{
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    dataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                 }
         }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following syntax (remove `Text` from Extended properties since it is used to import csv files) :

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new 
OleDbConnection(String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"HDR={1};IMEX=1;Readonly=1;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;\"",pathOnly ,header )))
{
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
        {
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
    }
}
```

If you have office 2007 or higher provider installed try using `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider since the it also support reading old excel formats.

If you are trying to import text files (csv) then it is better to use text parsing libraries such as :

- [TextFieldParser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx)
- [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)