# DataTable ColumnName Limitations?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel-interop, oledbdataadapter, datacolumn

I'm trying to read data from an Excel File into a `DataSet`, but my problem is the `DataTable` Column Names aren't matching what's in my Excel. It seems to be only Columns with long Column Names. In the `DataTable` Column Names it cuts off at some point.

Here's my attempt:

```
DataSet mainExcelDataToImport = new DataSet();
using (OleDbConnection mainExcelOleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection())
{
    string theMainExcelConnectionString = this.ExcelConnectionString.Replace("{FullFilePath}", this.SelectedFilePath);
    mainExcelOleDbConnection.ConnectionString = theMainExcelConnectionString;

    // Open
    mainExcelOleDbConnection.Open();

    string mainExcelSQL = "SELECT * FROM [{ExcelSheet}$]";
    mainExcelSQL = mainExcelSQL.Replace("{ExcelSheet}", selectedExcelSheet);

    using (OleDbCommand mainExcelOleDbCommand = mainExcelOleDbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        mainExcelOleDbCommand.CommandText = mainExcelSQL;
        mainExcelOleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // Prepare
        mainExcelOleDbCommand.Prepare();

        using (OleDbDataAdapter mainOleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(mainExcelOleDbCommand))
        {
            mainOleDbDataAdapter.Fill(mainExcelDataToImport);

            // Close
            mainExcelOleDbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a .xlsx I've tried:

```
A1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

TEST

'A12345.....' is the Column Name at A1

'TEST' is the Value at A2

When I check the `ColumnName` in the `DataTable` I get: 'A123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123' which is 64 characters.
```

How does the `ColumnName` `MaxLength` limitation work?

Can I get rid of it?

Is it maybe a limitation on the `OleDbDataAdapter`?

Any help / suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

64 characters is unusually long for the name of a database column. I've never seen a column name come anywhere near that length.

It seems odd that you would have a column name so long.

They have to be stored somewhere of course and so there is likely to be a maximum on any database software eg SQL server has a maximum of 128.  It would not surprise me if intermediate software like sqlclient had a lower limit.  Very long names are so unusual.

It's probably a limitation of the adapter.

You could try some of the alternatives mentioned in this thread:

[Best /Fastest way to read an Excel Sheet into a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261655/best-fastest-way-to-read-an-excel-sheet-into-a-datatable)

Or maybe you can just work with xml - and not a datatable.
Xml will be able to handle any size field that excel can.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/understanding-the-open-xml-file-formats
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet
I