# Get Excel data in DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, excel, file

I'm currently trying to access data from an Excel file in my C# Code. Thats my try:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filepath= ".../0f351ee0-0e7b-488b-80c5-db5da81f4bb5.xlsx";
            ReadExcel(file_path, ".xlsx");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    enter code here
        public static DataTable ReadExcel(string fileName, string fileExt)
        {
            string conn = string.Empty;
            DataTable dtexcel = new DataTable();
            if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)
                conn = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=Yes;IMEX=1';"; //for below excel 2007  
            else
                conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO';"; //for above excel 2007  
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con); //here we read data from sheet1  
                    oleAdpt.Fill(dtexcel); //fill excel data into dataTable  
                }
                catch { }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(dtexcel);
          
            return dtexcel;
```

the problem is that the DataTable is always empty. Where exactly can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best /Fastest way to read an Excel Sheet into a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261655/best-fastest-way-to-read-an-excel-sheet-into-a-datatable)

Comment: Instead of using the Access drivers, which may not even be installed, use a package that can read Excel directly, like the [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) package that not only opens a DbDataReader over an Excel file but can load the data from all sheets into a DataSet with a single call: `var ds=reader.AsDataSet();`

Comment: @tripleee that's not a good duplicate. Yes, the question is the same but almost all of the answers are outdated or problematic - both Excel interop and JET work only on Windows and can have bitness issues. In the last 9 years other, native .NET and cross-platform options have become available, like ExcelDataReader, Epplus, NPOI, ClosedXML and many others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the JET/Access driver can read Excel files as if they were databases, it has several problems, especially in the .NET Core era:

1. It's Windows-only
2. It needs to be installed. It can't be packaged with your application
3. The installed version must match the bitness (32/64-bit) of any Office components. This in turn means that *your* application must match Office's bitness.

There are libraries that can read Excel files directly. One such option is [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader), which opens a `DbDataReader` over an Excel sheet. It can handle both the obsolete `xls` format and the 16 year old `xlsx` format (yes, the "new" xlsx format was introduce in 2006, 16 years ago).

The generated data reader can be used to read the data or load a DataTable the same as any other data reader.

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
    {
        var table=new DataTable();
        table.Load(reader);
        ...
    }
}
```

ExcelDataReader has an extension that allows reading *all* sheets in a workbook into a DataSet, with one DataTable for each sheet.

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
    {
        var dataset= reader.AsDataSet();

        // The result of each spreadsheet is in dataset.Tables
    }
}
```

Comment: In the line `table.Load(reader);` I get the error `The specified method is not supported`.
How to properly transfer data to a DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I read from an Excel file:

```
public static DataSet Import(string path) 
{
    var dataStructure = new DataSet();

    // Create the connection string and connect to the excel table by OleDbConnection. 
    string connectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={path};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Cannot connect to the OLEDB (Excel) driver with the connection string \"{connectionString}\".\n{e}");

            return null;
        }

        DataTable sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in sheets.Rows)
            {
                var tableName = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                string sql = $"SELECT * FROM [{tableName}]";
                var oleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                oleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dataStructure, tableName);
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }

    return dataStructure;
}
```

I would highly recommend you to use the Open-XML-SDK for reading Excel files instead:
[Open-XML-SDK nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Open-XML-SDK)
This will make life a bit easier. e.g.:

```
SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, isEditable);
```

Comment: Is the connectionstring here the file path?

Comment: I edited my code snippet. The connection string does contain the file path in addition to other settings.

Comment: not supported on Dotnet Core