# Import Excel .xlsx file into vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I want to import my Excel .xlsx file into a datatable in vb.net in order to process the data later. My Excel file called Data.xlsx looks like this:

| Référence | Date | Concerned Numbers | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-A34 | 24.01.2022 | 738/3784 | Checked |
| 2022-A36 | 28.01.2022 | 7/3, 8733/28373,938/24755 |  |

and tried to use the code given by Ciarán here: [Best /Fastest way to read an Excel Sheet into a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261655/best-fastest-way-to-read-an-excel-sheet-into-a-datatable)

```
    Dim sSheetName As String = ""
    Dim sConnection As String
    Dim nOutputRow As Integer = 0
    Dim dtTablesList As DataTable
    Dim oleExcelCommand As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim oleExcelReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim oleExcelConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection

    sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Folder\Data.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"""

    oleExcelConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(sConnection)
    oleExcelConnection.Open()

    dtTablesList = oleExcelConnection.GetSchema("Tables")

    If dtTablesList.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        sSheetName = dtTablesList.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString
    End If

    dtTablesList.Clear()
    dtTablesList.Dispose()

    If sSheetName <> "" Then
        oleExcelCommand = oleExcelConnection.CreateCommand()
        oleExcelCommand.CommandText = "Select * From [" & sSheetName & "]"
        oleExcelCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        oleExcelReader = oleExcelCommand.ExecuteReader
        nOutputRow = 0
        While oleExcelReader.Read
        End While
        oleExcelReader.Close()
    End If

    oleExcelConnection.Close()
```

My problem is now that when I run that code and check the `dtTablesList` to see the content, the whole table is basically empty.
I only see this:
[image: After the code has been executed, I see this]

Am I missing here something or is my approach totally wrong?

Comment: At what line do you check `dtTablesList`? It is cleared and disposed in the middle of your code.

Comment: oh no. Ok that is my problem. I was so dumb to check the `dtTablesList` when it is disposed. My fault, sorry for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
While oleExcelReader.Read
End While
```

will let you process each row inside the loop.
This is good if you want to read and handle each field for each row individually, e.g. with `oleExcelReader.GetString(0)` etc.

If you just want to read the entire table, one way is:

```
...
dtTablesList.Clear()
dtTablesList.Dispose()

Dim dt As DataTable

If sSheetName <> "" Then
    oleExcelCommand = oleExcelConnection.CreateCommand()
    oleExcelCommand.CommandText = "Select * From [" & sSheetName & "]"
    oleExcelCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Using da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(oleExcelCommand)
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
    End Using
End If

oleExcelConnection.Close()
```

Comment: By using this, my problem is solved, however the first line in the excel files are not used as headers.

Comment: You can try to use `HDR=Yes` in the connection string.

Comment: is it actually normal that some content of my .xlsx-file is imported wrongly. I have for example a header called `Date of F.C.`, but the header in my datatable is called `Date of F#C#`. This means that the . is replaced by the #

Comment: @Cliff Phew I can't help you with that. You may have to ask another question about (I presume) the exact limitations of ACE / OLEDB. But I tested it quickly and see that too for dots.